# Bring the app window to front if already open Javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, window

In my HTML,

```
<a id="appLink" style="display:none" ></a>
```

in JS,

```
$("#appLink").prop("href", appSchemaURL);
$("#appLink").focus();
$("#appLink")[0].click();
```

How to bring the app window to front if already open?

Answer (score 0):

If you have opened the app window using window.open you can do something like this:

```
// safe window reference
var appWindow;

// when the user clicks the link:
// set the focus if window exists
if (window.focus && !appWindow.closed) {appWindow.focus()}

// OR open window if window does not exist    
if (appWindow.closed) {appWindow = window.open(appUrl,'name')}
    return false;
}
```

Comment: how to confirm this link is valid?

Comment: check the appWindow.location.

Why do you want to check the link?

Comment: I need to set a variable to false if the app is not installed.

Comment: Also I need to open the link in the way i did in the above code, not through window.open()

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution as,

```
var appWin = $("#appLink")[0].click();  
appWin.focus();
```

Thanks...

Comment: But one issue. The first time, the window appears to front. If I come back to main window and click the link again, the app window updates its content but doesn't come back to front. Any solution?